# how to "allow from hostname" in nginx config

Tags: nginx

I'm currently doing this in my nginx.conf:

```
allow 1.2.3.4;
deny;
```

What I'd really like to do is this:

```
allow my.domain.name;
deny;
```

I.e., I want nginx to do an A record lookup on my.domain.name at the time of the request, and if it matches the IP that the request is coming from, then allow it. I don't see any built-in mechanism to do this however. Anybody have a native way to do this before I start coding something custom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such feature in official distribution of nginx. Beacause it may heavily reduce performance.

Third party modules http://wiki.nginx.org/3rdPartyModules also doesn't contain this feature.

Comment: I don't think that not offering the feature at all can be attributed solely to performance. Clearly it's slower, but that should be my choice to make. (Apache, for example, gives me the option, just like with DNS resolution of access logs.) In this case, I'm more than willing to trade the time required to do a DNS lookup for a feature which will only ever be used sporadically by one person. So I guess I'm off to write my own.

Comment: Furthermore - it would be of some use if it only looked up the hostname at configuration load time.  That would eliminate any performance considerations, while improving maintainability of config files,...

Answer (score 22):

ngx_http_rdns_module does what you need: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/rdns/ (https://github.com/flant/nginx-http-rdns)

### Summary

This module allows to make a reverse DNS (rDNS) lookup for incoming connection and provides simple access control of incoming hostname by allow/deny rules (similar to HttpAccessModule allow/deny directives; regular expressions are supported). Module works with the DNS server defined by the standard resolver directive.

### Example

```
location / {
    resolver 127.0.0.1;

    rdns_deny badone\.example\.com;

    if ($http_user_agent ~* FooAgent) {
        rdns on;
    }

    if ($rdns_hostname ~* (foo\.example\.com)) {
        set $myvar foo;
    }

    #...
}
```

Comment: how do I install this module ?

Answer (score 13):

*This answer is an alternative which let resolution of domain out of nginx but targets the exact same goal, being able to have resolved ips included in nginx configuration.*

1) Create a file `allowed-domain.list` which contains the domains you want to grant access to :

```
jean-paul.mydomain.com
rufus.mydomain.com
robert.mydomain.com
```

2) Create a bash script `domain-resolver.sh` which do the lookup for you :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
filename="$1"
while read -r line
do
        ddns_record="$line"
        if [[ !  -z  $ddns_record ]]; then
                resolved_ip=`getent ahosts $line | awk '{ print $1 ; exit }'`
                if [[ !  -z  $resolved_ip ]]; then
                        echo "allow $resolved_ip;# from $ddns_record"
                fi
        fi
done < "$filename"
```

3) Give the right permission to this script `chmod +x domain-resolver.sh`

4) Add a cron job which produces a valid nginx configuration and restarts nginx :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
/pathtoscript/domain-resolver.sh /pathtodomainlist/allowed-domain.list > /pathtooutputdir/allowed-ips-from-domains.conf
service nginx reload > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This can be a `@daily` job or you can have it run every hour, minute, sec...

5) Update your nginx configuration to take this output into account :

```
include /pathtooutputdir/allowed-ips-from-domains.conf;
deny all;
```

You can improve this adding an ip format check, prevent ipv6 if you don't want it, group everything in a single file...

Comment: This worked perfectly! thanks, bonus was that it was easy to setup and add to nginx proxy manager as well

Comment: So easy to follow and working perfectly. Great solution!

Comment: This is a top notch solution -- wasn't looking for this but this is even better :)

Comment: Great solution although really is a shame that NGINX can't resolve CNAME records directly which would really help with dynamic public IP addresses on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

you can add this to return not found for any domain that do not match with yours

```
if ($host  !~* (yourhostname.com)) {
      return 404;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lua script.
You need to install nginx-mod-http-lua and lua-nginx-dns modules.
The example nginx lua script will be:

```
        location /test/ {
                access_by_lua_block {
                        local resolver = require "nginx.dns.resolver";
                        local r, err = resolver:new {
                                nameservers = { "8.8.8.8", "1.1.1.1" },
                                retrans = 5,    -- timeout retransmits
                                timeout = 500,  -- 500msec
                                no_random = true, -- always start from the first name server
                        };

                        if not r then
                                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to instantiate the DNS resolver: " .. err)
                                return
                        end

                        local answers, err, tries = r:query("my.domain.name", nil, {});
                        if not answers then
                                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "failed to query the DNS server: " .. err)
                                return
                        end

                        if answers.errcode then
                                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "server returned error code: " .. answers.errcode .. ": " .. answers.errstr)
                                return;
                        end

                        for i, ans in ipairs(answers) do
                                if ans.address == ngx.var.remote_addr then
                                        return
                                end
                        end

                        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Not allow IP : " .. ngx.var.remote_addr);
                        ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN);
                }
        }
```